# How do I list the non-default settings in ccsm?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

Does anyone know how to extract all non-default settings from CCSM?

I use a few computers and finally managed to set up one of them just the way I like it. Now I want all non-default settings listed somehow so I can apply them to the other computers.

I guess I could do a backup of the `~/.config` directory, reset everything and run a `diff` with the backed up directory. I was hoping someone could know a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install Compiz configuration settings manager (CCSM)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open it, Go to *Preferences → Profile&Backend tab → Export*
3. Select path, Enter a file name then Save
4. A message dialog pop up:

   > Do you want to skip default option values while exporting your profile?
5. Click *Yes*